# c++ virtual functions with Linked List

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I'm running into some problems while trying to use a virtual function within my classes. 
I'm using a Linked List to store Employee, Staff and Managers - which inherit each other (Staff and Managers inherit Employee base class).

I need to be able to access a function called getType which returns either "Staff Member" or "Manager" based on which class it is.

this snipit of code is my creation of staff and managers.

```
    Staff staff4 = { "Lisa", "22/02/2012", 0004, HR, 8.9, 34.50 };
    Employee* pStaff4 = &staff4;
    Employee& testStaff4 = staff4;
    myList->addInFront(testStaff4);

    Staff staff5 = { "Jade", "23/03/2014", 0003, HR, 6.4, 38.50 };
    Employee* pStaff5 = &staff5;
    Employee& testStaff5 = staff5;
    myList->addInFront(testStaff5);

    Manager manager1 = { "Lily", "01/09/2012", 0001, MARKETING, 75968 };
    Employee* pMan1 = &manager1;
    Employee& testMan1 = manager1;
    myList->addInFront(testMan1);

    Manager manager2 = { "Craig", "27/03/2011", 0002, HR, 82478 };
    Employee* pMan2 = &manager2;
    Employee& testMan2 = manager2;
    myList->addInFront(testMan2);

    //cout << pStaff5->getType();
    //system("pause");
```

This is my employee.h (i've taken out other functions to save space on this post)

```
 class Employee
{
protected:
    string name;
    string startDate;
    unsigned long empNumber;
    string dept;
public:
    Employee()  {};
    Employee(string, string, unsigned long, string);

    virtual const string getType()
    {
        return "Emp";
    }
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
private:
    unsigned long salary;
public:
    virtual const string getType()
    {
        return "Manager";
    }
};

class Staff : public Employee
{
private:
    float hourlyRate;
    float hoursPerWeek;
public:
    const string getType()
    {
        return "Staff Member";
    }
};
```

and finally this is how i'm attempting to call the getType() function:

```
void displayList(const List& list)
{
    List temp(list);
    while (!temp.isEmpty())
    {

        cout << temp.first()->item.getType() << "\n";
        cout << temp.first()->item.getName() << "\n";
        temp.deleteFirst();
    }

}
```

Here is my list header and .cpp

list.h

```
//#include <string>
#include "Employees.h"

#define Item Employee

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Item item;
    Node* next;
};

class List
{
private: 
    Node* head;
    Node* end() const;
    void copy(const List&);
    void destroy();
public:
    List();
    List(const List&);
    ~List();
    List& operator=(const List&);
    bool operator==(const List&);
    bool isEmpty() const;
    Node* first() ;
    Item last() const;
    List tail() const;
    void addInFront(const Item&);
    void addAtEnd(const Item&);
    void deleteFirst();
    Node* search(const long);
    bool searchDelete(const long);
};
```

list.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <assert.h> 

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
}

List::List(const List& otherList) : head(nullptr)
{
    copy(otherList);
}

bool List::isEmpty() const
{
    return (head == nullptr);
}

Node* List::first() 
{
    assert(head != nullptr);
    return head;
}

void List::deleteFirst()
{
    if (head != NULL) 
    {
        Node* tmp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
    }
}

void List::addInFront(const Item& data)
{
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    assert(nodePtr != nullptr);
    nodePtr -> item = data;
    nodePtr ->next = head;
    head = nodePtr;
}

Node* List::search(const long longID)
{

}


bool List::searchDelete(const long longID)
{

    Node *temp, *prevNode;
    temp = head;
    prevNode = NULL;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {

    }
}

Node* List::end() const
{
    if (head == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        Node* nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next != nullptr)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        return nodePtr;
    }
}

void List::addAtEnd(const Item& data)
{
    Node* nodePtr = new Node;
    assert(nodePtr != nullptr);
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = nodePtr;
            nodePtr->item = data;
        }
        else
        {
            nodePtr->item = data;
            Node* ptr = end();
            ptr->next = nodePtr;
        }
}

List& List::operator=(const List& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        destroy();
        copy(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
}

void List::copy(const List& otherList)
{

}

void List::destroy()
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        Node* ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}

List::~List()
{

}
```

apologies about the length of these files.

[image]

I'm confused as to why it won't call the appropriate virtual function, as you can see in the first code snipit that i used pStaff5->getType() and that worked - however I can't access the nodes like that once i've stored them in a linked list...(can I?)

Kind regards
Craig

Comment: You need to show `List` - it probably is not capable of storing subclasses of `Employee`.

Comment: Yea, what is the definition of the "list" that you're sending to displayList().   I'll bet you that it's list<Employee> list;

Comment: What does `first()->item` return? It should be a reference or pointer type for polymorphism to work properly.

Comment: @AtlasC1 it returns a structure called Node which holds an item and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: @aschepler I have added my List.h and List.cpp to the original post - sorry about the size of them - I didnt know how much information you needed!

Comment: If your linked list nodes store objects of type Employee then storing any objects that inherit from Employee will result in object slicing. That is your problem. You need to store Employee pointers in your linked list nodes.

Comment: @Craig - On the side, your assignment operator implementation destroys the list before it is known whether the copy will work.  Not a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

Your list nodes store an `Item` but that is only the base class. When you try to put a `Manager` or `Staff` in the list only the base class part of the object is copied into the list (this is called ["slicing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)) and not the derived parts of the object.

When you call the virtual function you only get the base class overrider for the virtual, because the object stored in the list is only an `Employee`.

(You should consider making `Node` and `List` into templates, instead of doing `#define Item Employee`)